# Search suggestions doesn't work on first run of application

Tags: android, searchview

I have problem with search suggestions placed in main activity. Sometimes suggestions don't appear on first run of application(eg for new users), when it is reopened everything works fine.

I found out that content provider query is sometimes not triggered during first run. Reason for this is that `searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());` sometimes returns null.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
    if(searchableInfo != null){
        setSearchableInfo(mSearchView, searchableInfo);
    } else {
        Log.d("Problem", "searchableInfo null");
        handle.postDelayed(waitAndRetry, 10000);
    }
}
```

I fixed it by checking searchableInfo again after delay.

```
Runnable waitAndRetry = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("Problem", "retry after second");
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        setSearchableInfo(mSearchView, searchableInfo);
    }
};
```

Although it is working with this delay I find it disturbing that `SearchManager(?)` is not fully ready when activity starts. I suppose it may be connected with the fact that I populate `db` during first run. It is not long operation (below 100 ms) but I guess it may be the reason.

Anyway, is there a way to make sure that when I start activity for the first time `SearchableInfo` will be ready and (from user perspective) suggestions will work?

Comment: Are you using an FTS virtual table?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchActivity.class);
```

Important thing is to have your `SearchActivity` in the same package as the activity from which you are retrieving the `SearchableInfo`.